# htaccess: multiple redirections depending on domain name

Tags: .htaccess

I have a server and a few domains and two webpages. Can't figure out how to do the following:

```
A.com -> root\
www.A.com -> root\
B.com -> root\
www.B.com -> root\
C.com -> root\folder1\
www.C.com -> root\folder1\
```

By the way. What is the 'and' logical operator used in htaccess? I found that 'or' is [OR] but [AND] doesn't seem to work. And what is the language htaccess is written in:)?

UPDATE

I made a mistake in the question though. Here's what I'd really want to do. DNS is set for the domain A.com to point to the root folder of the server. Now I would like to set the following redirections:

Any domain other than C.com and other than D.com redirects (301) to www.A.com. A.com points to the root folder of the server anyway and that is set in DNS.

Domain www.C.com points to the folder 'folder1' on the server. Can it be set in htaccess?

Now domains C.com, www.D.com and D.com redirects to www.C.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your A and B domains, use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(a|b).com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /root/ [L]
```

The `(www\.)?` allows you to use both with and without www (the ? means "the preceding block zero or one time").

`(a|b)` means "a or b". You can add more domains in there using more pipes (a|b|d|e)

For the other one:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?c.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /root/folder1/ [L]
```

If you want www.A.com/hello.php to redirect to /root/hello.php then add `$1` after the /root/ in the RewriteRule (goes for both rules)

[AND] does not exist because it is implicit when you use multiple RewriteConds. Something like this:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.a.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.b.com$

already means has [AND] implied and thus will never work (because a domain can never be a.com and b.com at the same time).

---

***update***
Answer to your new question:

"Any domain other than C.com and other than D.com redirects (301) to www.A.com. A.com points to the root folder of the server anyway and that is set in DNS."

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?(c|d).com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.a.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

"Domain www.C.com points to the folder 'folder1' on the server. Can it be set in htaccess?"

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.c.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder1/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder1/$1 [L,R]
```

"Now domains C.com, www.D.com and D.com redirects to www.C.com."

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^c.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?d.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.c.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I added a question to your question in a new question because it was too many characters.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: I updated my answer ;)

Comment: The first part works. The second does not redirect to folder1.

Comment: Should it redirect or just show its contents? To redirect, add the R flag to it (so it becomes `[L,R]` at the end of the RewriteRule

Comment: It is now [L,R]. It now redirects but gets looped even though the L flag is in place. So the result is: www.c.com/folder1/folder1/folder1/..and  so on. There is no .htaccess file in folder1.

Comment: Ah of course, sorry. Updated my answer.

Comment: There is some progress but we're still not there. Now the result is: Error 404: The requested URL /folder1/index.phpfolder1/folder1/folder1/folder1/folder1/..and so on, was not found on this server.

Comment: Hmm, I'm at a loss then. The rule is now almost exactly as one that I use myself. No idea how to fix it.

Comment: I removed the character ^ so that the additional condition now is: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/folder1/ . And it redirects correctly, but the address in the address bar is now www.c.com/folder1. Wish I could have it as: www.c.com.

Comment: Anyways thanks for a lot of help! I appreciate it very much.

Comment: That's why you should remove the `R` flag again. It redirects, making the url change.

Comment: BTW, if it works and you're happy with it, please accept my answer as the correct one (the checkmark below the answer's vote score)

Comment: I'm relatively new to stackoverflow so thanks for all the tips on using this website.